# NIntegrate on indefinite integral involving a lognormal function

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to numerically integrate and the plot the following
$$ \psi(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{k}\frac{\sin kr}{kr}\exp\left[ -\frac{\ln^{2}(k/k_{0})}{2\sigma^2} \right] $$
over a range of $r$ for $\sigma=0.8$ and $k_{0}=10^{10}$. Since I want to make the plots dimensionless, I keep the $x$-axis as $k_{0}r$ and evaluate the integral over $r\in (\epsilon,6/k_{0})$, where $\epsilon$ is very small so that Mathematica does not produce warning messages. Below is the small code that I have

```
k0=10^10;sig=0.8;
P[k_]:=(1.0/Sqrt[2*Pi*Pi*sig^2])*Exp[-(Log[k/k0]^2)/(2*sig^2)];
psi[r_]:=NIntegrate[(Sin[k*r]/(r*k^2))*P[k],{k,0,Infinity},Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
rlist = Table[i, {i, 10^-12, 6.0/k0, (6.0*10^-10 - 10^-12)/750}];
psilist = Quiet[Table[psi[i], {i, 10^-12, 6.0/k0, (6.0*10^-10 - 10^-12)/750}]];
ListPlot[Transpose[{k0*rlist, psilist}],Joined -> True]
```

When I evaluate and plot the integral over the list of values of r, I get the following graph
[[image: Upper limit <span class=]$k=\infty$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b93pK.jpg)
The plot that I am expecting should not have bumps like this. However, it appears that if I choose the upper limit of the integral as $10^{12}$, I get a smoother plot
[image]
Can anyone tell me what is causing this? This apparently happens for $\sigma>0.6$ for some odd reason.

Comment: Is `pi` supposed to be `Pi`?  And `\[Psi]` is `psi` perhaps?  What are the two tables for? How did you produce the troublesome plot? Why did you turn off `”SymbolicProcessing”` on such an oscillatory integral?

Comment: I edited the code. The table rlist is a list of values of r over which psilist is evaluated. I think I turned off SymbolicProcessing because I thought it cuts down on the time it takes for evaluation.

Comment: Your observation indicates numerical erasing problem for `k>> k0`. Check for example value of `Exp[-(Log[k/k0]^2)/(2*sig^2)]`  for `k/k0== 100`

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what 'numerical erasing' means.